# How to enable chown commands via Hadoop NFS Gateway

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nfs

I have a use-case where I have enabled NFS gateway for my hadoop system following this nice [guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html). I have mounted it on another machine via:

```
sudo mount -v -t nfs -o vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock,noacl $ip:/dataDir /mountDir
```

Now there is a use-case where I need to run chown command to a file in `dataDir` folder, so I run following:

```
chown user2  /mountDir/sample.txt
```

But this gives error:

> chown: changing ownership of `/mountDir/sample.txt': Permission denied

and I get following in NFS gateway logs:

```
18/04/05 23:54:25 WARN nfs3.RpcProgramNfs3: Exception
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Non-super user cannot change owner
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAttrOp.setOwner(FSDirAttrOp.java:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.setOwner(FSNamesystem.java:1669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.setOwner(NameNodeRpcServer.java:703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.setOwner(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:464)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
```

I also trying added following in `/etc/nfs.map` file as mentioned in [docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html#User_authentication_and_mapping) and an error faced doing this detailed [here](https://serverfault.com/q/906338/392186):

```
uid 0 594903  //where 0 is uid of root on another machine, and 594903 is uid of hdfs which is superuser on datanode machine where NFS gateway is running.
```

But I still get this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied. user=root is not the owner of inode=sample3.txt
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkOwner(FSPermissionChecker.java:250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1771)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1755)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkOwner(FSDirectory.java:1724)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAttrOp.setOwner(FSDirAttrOp.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.setOwner(FSNamesystem.java:1669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.setOwner(NameNodeRpcServer.java:703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.setOwner(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:464)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
```

Any idea how to get this done?